# Why are people getting Documentation Pioneer badge in December 2016?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158/documentation-pioneer) for Documentation Pioneer badge says:

> Contributed 3+ substantive pieces of documentation **in the first
>   month of documentation**.

This should mean that the badge should no longer be achievable now given that first month of documentation ended in late August.

The badge was awarded from [July 21, 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158?page=40) to [August 20, 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6158?page=1) which is the first month of documentation.

Yet today I see that two more users were awarded this badge on December 13th 2016 and December 19th 2016. How did that happen?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You've heard of the Eternal September? Well, Documentation is in the "Eternal August" period, where the sheer volume of low-quality contributions make it appear that it must still be in its very first month post-release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when users merge accounts. We always merge accounts into the lower user ID, which isn't always the user that has the badge they've earned. So when the merge is complete, they'll receive the badge again the next time the process runs that awards it, which records the new date that they earned the badge.

**Hint:** You can usually spot when a merge happens because the user will have a [long list of badges all awarded on the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013580/zurfyx?tab=activity&sort=badges).